# flutter 2 fcm ios apn issue

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

The firebase FCM is not working for me in flutter 2.2.2, am trying to implement push notification in my ios app and am getting this error :

> 8.3.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '*************'.
> Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be
> sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.

It’s been one month since this problem occurred.

I followed the step in this [article](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/) and [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging)

the push notifications works fine in Android the problem is with the iOS

this is my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
// Use Firebase library to configure APIs
FirebaseApp.configure()
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

  let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
    options: authOptions,
    completionHandler: { _, _ in }
  )
} else {
  let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: facing same issue. any update @Rex?

Comment: after the release of the IOS 15 and Xcode 13 everything just worked fine

Answer (score 0):

you have to add

```
Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
```

before

```
return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```